# C# Integration Tests with SQL Server not returning expected data

Tags: c#, sql-server, xunit

I've been trying to test the delete operation with integration testing (XUnit, Moq, FluentAssertions), but I don't understand why the result is not what I expected.

This is the test:

```
 [Fact]
        public async Task DeleteAsync_DeletesRoleModelByGivenId()
        {
            var fakeRoleModel = new Faker<RoleModel>()
                .RuleFor(r => r.Id, Guid.NewGuid())
                .RuleFor(r => r.Name, "Role Deleted")
                .RuleFor(r => r.Description, f => f.Lorem.Paragraph())
                .RuleFor(r => r.CreatedDate, DateTime.Now)
                .RuleFor(r => r.UpdatedDate, DateTime.Now)
                .RuleFor(r => r.Deleted, false)
                .Generate();

            var roleToDelete = await _rolesRepository.CreateAsync(fakeRoleModel);

            var client = _integrationTestFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await client.DeleteAsync($"/api/roles/{roleToDelete.Id}");

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var deletedRoleById = await _rolesRepository.GetByIdAsync(roleToDelete.Id);
            deletedRoleById.Deleted.ShouldBeTrue();
        }
```

The controller for the roleModel should not delete records from the database, instead it should mark the deleted property as true.

Currently, this test is failing. More specifically, in this line

```
  deletedRoleById.Deleted.ShouldBeTrue();
```

The status we get is OK, and if I check the data using SQL server Management Studio, Deleted has been marked as true.

Why is the query from this line, after the model has been updated:

```
var deletedRoleById = await _rolesRepository.GetByIdAsync(roleToDelete.Id);
```

returning an object that has Deleted = false (Initial value)?.

If remove the previous repository query and another request is sent to the controller to get the role by Id:

```
 var secondClient = _integrationTestFactory.CreateClient();
 var roleModel = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<RoleModel>($"/api/roles/{roleToDelete.Id}");

 roleModel.Name.ShouldBe("Role Deleted");
 roleModel.Deleted.ShouldBe(true);
```

The test passed and the deleted property is true as it should be.

This is the RoleModel:

```
 public class RoleModel : BaseRecordModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RoleFeatureModel> RoleFeatures { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RoleUserModel> RoleUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the DeleteAsync method used in the controller, from the
roleRepository:

```
 public virtual async Task DeleteAsync(Guid id)
 {
      var entity = await GetEntityByIdAsync(id);
      entity.Deleted = true;
      _db.Set<TEntity>().Update(entity);

      await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

This is the GetByIdAsync method:

```
public override async Task<RoleModel> GetByIdAsync(Guid Id)
{
   var roleEntity = await _db.Roles
                         .Include(r => r.RoleFeatures)
                             .ThenInclude(rf => rf.Feature)
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == Id);

   return _mapper.Map<RoleModel>(roleEntity);
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Anyway to include what `_rolesRepository.GetByIdAsync` looks like and also what your `RoleModel` looks like?

Comment: Is `client` using the same instance of the repository as the test? Or, is the repository in `client` referencing the same `DbContext` as `_rolesRepository`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm making a bunch of assumptions about the structure of your code here and I'm also assuming you're using EF as your ORM...

According to the EF Core documentation on [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works#the-life-of-a-query)

> For each item in the result set
> If the query is a tracking query, EF checks if the data represents an entity already in the change tracker for the context instance
> If so, the existing entity is returned
> If not, a new entity is created, change tracking is set up, and the new entity is returned
> If the query is a no-tracking query, then a new entity is always created and returned

Similarly, for [EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/#finding-entities-using-a-query)

> When results are returned from the database, objects that do not exist in the context are attached to the context. If an object is already in the context, the existing object is returned (the current and original values of the object's properties in the entry are not overwritten with database values).

So, I'm making a guess here but I'd say that the problem is that when you call `_rolesRepository.CreateAsync` in the test, the `DbContext` used by `_rolesRepository` begins tracking the created entity.

Then, you create the client and send an HTTP request to your service. I assume this resolves to `RolesController` which has a new, scoped instance of the repository injected with a new instance of the `DbContext`. You delete the entity on this instance of the `DbContext`.

Back in your test, `_rolesRepository`'s `DbContext` is still tracking the entity that it started tracking when you called `CreateAsync`. So, when you call `GetByIdAsync` it returns that entity that is already being tracked, rather than refreshing the data from the database.

It works if you make another call to the client, because you're hitting `RolesController` again, which is getting a new repository injected with a new `DbContext` that isn't tracking the entity already. So, when you call `GetByIdAsync` on that `DbContext`, the entity is loaded from the database.

If all this is accurate, you could try setting up your fixture such that it can give you a new instance of the repository. Then in the setup phase you get a new instance of the repository and call `CreateAsync`. Then make your HTTP request to your end point. Then get another new instance of the repository, call `GetByIdAsync` on that and check if the entity is how you expect.